# Python 3.4, add numbers up to an integer

Tags: python, python-3.4

What I need to do is create a function where a previously entered input (in this case y) gets all the numbers up to it added up.

Or, as my teacher put it:

It should then find the sum of all the numbers starting at 1 up to the number typed in.

For example, if I type in a 10 the function should return 55.
Because:

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55
```

If I type in a 12 the function should return 78.
Because:

```
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12 = 78
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
if y == 1: 
    return y 
elif y <= 1 and y <= 999999999: 
    print(sum(y))
```

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: I tried using range, but that doesn't work, and I think it needs an if statement, but I'm not sure how to write it. What I have now is:

def sum(y):
    if y == 1:
        return y
    elif y <= 1 and y <= 999999999:
        print(
sum(y)

Comment: The purpose of SO is not that you should post problems that you haven't even tried to solve yourself. I can hardly see where you can go wrong if you if you make any affort to solve it. If you got stuck somewhere, please point that out by showing what you've tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: can you post your code, so we can help you

Comment: This isn't the place to learn basic python. A better place to start is the python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Here's the code for the guy who asked for it: 

y = int(input("Please enter a number."))

def sum(y):
    if y == 1:
        return y
    elif y <= 1 and y <= 999999999:
        print(
sum(y)

Comment: If you had paid attention in school you would remember that there is a simple formula for this.

Comment: for sum of numbers 1 to n, the sum is equal to (n(n+1))/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your code:

```
if y == 1: 
    return y 
elif y <= 1 and y <= 999999999: 
    print(sum(y))
```

First, why are you using `return` in `if` part but using `print()` in `elif` part?

Then, simply do something like this:

```
def function_name(number):
    return sum(range(1, number+1))
```

---

**Demo:**

For example, the number is `10`:

```
print(function_name(10))
```

**Output:**

```
55
```

---

`range()` will give a generator like `1, 2, 3...8, 9, 10` here. And `sum()` can do something like `1 + 2 + 3...8 + 9 + 10` that you want.

Comment: Oh. I knew how to do that part, and I knew it would work, so I didn't want to have to replace it later. And I was going to replace the prints with returns later, but to test it I was going to use print.

Comment: That is...really helpful. Thank you. I wouldn't have even known that existed if you hadn't pointed it out.

Comment: There's no advantage to using a `lambda` over a standard definition here, including simplicity. It just replaces `def` with `lambda` and has an implied `return`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, and I think that will confused OP. So that's why I didn't put it in my answer ;)

Comment: But it's not simpler at all. There's literally no benefit to it here.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes...just as you said. Should I delete my comment?

Comment: I probably would, but there's no pressing need.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 However, I did it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an assignment, so it's better that you try it for yourself instead of getting a complete answer from the internet.

However I can point you in the right direction.

In your code:

```
elif y <= 1 and y <= 999999999: 
print(sum(y))
```

Ask yourself if the first line makes sense. If y is smaller than one, than surely it is also smaller than 9999....
Try to think of the correct operator here.

What you're looking to do (assuming this is an assignment to learn loops) is a simple loop that starts at 1, and ends at y, in which you have an addition.

Answer (score -1):

you need to know about range:

> range(start, stop[, step])
>
> This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1. If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 * step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero (or else ValueError is raised).

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1,10)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> range(1,10, 2)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

> sum(iterable[, start])
>
> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. start defaults to 0. The iterable‘s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

```
def my_sum(n):
    return sum(range(n))
```

Comment: Thanks for making this clear.

Comment: For a cut-and-paste answer to a low-quality question? Your guess is as good as mine...